How to clone or duplicate an Analytic Rule
How can you clone or duplicate an Analytic Rule that resides in Microsoft Sentinel, using either PowerShell or Azure CLI?
The cloned Analytic Rule will require a new ruleId and name but all other properties can remain the same.
$resourceGroupName = "XYZ" 
$workspaceName = "abc" # Get all analytic rules 
$analyticRules = Get-AzSentinelAlertRule -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -WorkspaceName $workspaceName 
foreach ($rule in $analyticRules) { # Duplicate each rule 
$newRule = $rule 
$newRule.DisplayName = "_" + $rule.DisplayName 
$newRule.Id = $null # Clear ID for new rul creation # Create the duplicated rule # /// 
New-AzOperationalInsightsSavedSearch -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -WorkspaceName $workspaceName -Properties $newRule.Properties 
#? New-AzSentinelAlertRule ? parameters to add 
}

Tried using Sentinel related PowerShell module and functions.

Can you add the code you have tried so far. @Jason Smyth

$resourceGroupName = "XYZ"
$workspaceName = "abc"
Get all analytic rules
$analyticRules = Get-AzSentinelAlertRule -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -WorkspaceName $workspaceName
foreach ($rule in $analyticRules) {
Duplicate each rule
$newRule = $rule
$newRule.DisplayName = "_" + $rule.DisplayName
$newRule.Id = $null # Clear ID for new rule creation
Create the duplicated rule
/// New-AzOperationalInsightsSavedSearch -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -WorkspaceName $workspaceName -Properties $newRule.Properties
#? New-AzSentinelAlertRule ? parameters to add
}

Any error is throwing with the above code? @Jason Smyth


How to clone or duplicate an Analytic Rule:

You can use below PowerShell script to clone an Analytic rule and it worked for me as shown below.
$rg = "xxxx"
$ws = "workjah"
$ars = Get-AzSentinelAlertRule -ResourceGroupName $rg -WorkspaceName $ws
foreach ($rule in $ars) {
  $newRule = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    DisplayName = "Cloned-" + $rule.DisplayName
    Enabled = $rule.Enabled
    # you can add the required properties based on the requirement
  }}
$created = New-AzSentinelAlertRule -ResourceGroupName $rg -WorkspaceName $ws -RuleId $newRule


Also you can refer set-Azsentinel.ps1 script to update analytic rule properties.

Thank you so much for your response @Jahnavi.
Just one quick question. IF you don't change any other Properties (that are not required), will they just get cloned in the 'New' rule that is generated?
Cheers
Jason S

Yes you just need to pass it as its original value. Eg: $ars.query @JasonSmyth
